# OpenHardwareMonitor not publishing to WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, openhardwaremonitor

According to the docs, OpenHardwareMonitor should publish 2 class (Hardware and Sensor) to the WMI but I cannot see any. I OpenHardwareMonitor has full read & write access to WMI so I'm not sure what's wrong. Am I even going about it the right way and should you be able to see those classes?

[image]

**EDIT**

Probably a cause of the same problem but when attempting to use the namespace OpenHardwareMonitor in my c# app

```
using OpenHardwareMonitor;
```

it does not recognise it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the .dll to my resources. Rookie error